# EF 6 dynamic model configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use custom validation attributes instead of the built in DataAnnotation ones. In the DbContext I run through the entities with reflection and configure the model based on these attributes. Unfortunately the following code doesn't work for integer properties. It is probably because it a cannot find the suitable overload for the "Property" method.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method should return the 
/// property configuration object of the modelbuilder
/// mb.Entity<User>().Property(p=>p.Age)
/// </summary>
private PrimitivePropertyConfiguration GetStringPropertyConfiguration(DbModelBuilder mb, Type entityType, string propertyName)
{
    //mb.Entity<User>()
    var structuralConfiguration = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(mb, null);
    //p=>p.Age
    var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(param, propertyName), param);
    //.Property()
    var propertyMethod = structuralConfiguration.GetType().GetMethod("Property", new[] { propertyExpression.GetType() });

    if (propertyMethod != null)
    {
        var stringpropertyConfiguration =
            propertyMethod.Invoke(structuralConfiguration, new[] {propertyExpression}) as
                PrimitivePropertyConfiguration;
        return stringpropertyConfiguration;

    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("This should not happen");
    }
}
```

//to test

```
public class Entity
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntegerProperty { get; set; }
}

var stringPropertyConfig = GetStringPropertyConfiguration(mb, typeof (Entity), "StringProperty");
var intPropertyConfig = GetStringPropertyConfiguration(mb, typeof(Entity), "IntegerProperty");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `Expression<Func<>>` strongly typed to your property return type.

Something like this would work for a property of type `int` :

```
private PrimitivePropertyConfiguration GetStructPropertyConfiguration(DbModelBuilder mb, Type entityType, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
{
  var structuralConfiguration = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity")
        .MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(mb, null);
  var param = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(entityType);

  var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, propertyType);
  var expressionType = typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression);

  var lambdaMethod = expressionType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Lambda").FirstOrDefault();

  var genericLambdaMethod = lambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(funcType);

  var prop = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(param, propertyName);

  var inv = genericLambdaMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { prop, new[] { param } });

  var propertyMethod = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Property").FirstOrDefault();

  var propertyMethodGeneric = propertyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);

  var mapping = propertyMethodGeneric.Invoke(structuralConfiguration , new[]{inv}) 
        as PrimitivePropertyConfiguration;

  return mapping;
}
```